# Button refreshes the page instead of just changing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see what I mean [here](https://codepen.io/merkur0/full/bvZKMz/)

What I want to achieve is that the number remains in Fahrenheit until I click the switch button again.

My JS code:

```
$.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=&lon=", function(json){
  var temp = json.main.temp;
  var ftemp = (temp * 1.8) + 32
  var celsius = true;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#temperature").html(temp);
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
    celsius = !celsius;
    if (celsius)
      {
        $("#temperature").html(temp);
      }
    else
      {
        $("#temperature").html(ftemp);
        $("#button").html("F");
      }
  })
  })
});
```

Comment: Why are you putting `$(document).ready()` inside the callback of an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted this in your question, but your "button" is actually an anchor.

```
<a id="button" href="">C</a>
```

Since there is no `href`, it'll default to the current page and refresh it.

So you have to prevent this, by doing this in your `click` event handler:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- will stop the page from refreshing
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` is causing the page to reload when it is clicked.

Use `preventDefult` to prevent this behavior:

```js
$.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=&lon=", function(json) {
  var temp = json.main.temp;
  var ftemp = (temp * 1.8) + 32
  var celsius = true;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#temperature").html(temp);
    $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  // <-- here
      celsius = !celsius;
      if (celsius) {
        $("#temperature").html(temp);
      } else {
        $("#temperature").html(ftemp);
        $("#button").html("F");
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <h1>Local Weather App</h1>
  <div id="data">
    <div id="temperature">

    </div>
    <a id="button" href="">C</a>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `href` attribute from your `a` element:

```js
$.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=&lon=", function(json){
  var temp = json.main.temp;
  var ftemp = (temp * 1.8) + 32
  var celsius = true;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#temperature").html(temp);
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
    celsius = !celsius;
    if (celsius)
      {
        $("#temperature").html(temp);
      }
    else
      {
        $("#temperature").html(ftemp);
        $("#button").html("F");
      }
  })
  })
});
```

```html
<center>
<h1>Local Weather App</h1>
<div id = "data">
  <div id ="temperature">
  </div>
  <a id="button">C</a>
</div>  
</center>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's an important thing about this. If you remove the `href` from your anchor, when you hover it the cursor won't be `pointer`. On iOs, click events only trigger on elements with `cursor: pointer`. You can put this trough css. Weird, right?